# Missing 'type' parameter

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

when I m giving driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); in my script ,i m getting error Missing 'type' parameter . here I have noticed that when I set the profile in Firefox( in the script) then I get this error but without setting profile in the script the same command works fine.
selenium version 3.8.1
geckodriver: 0.19.1
Firefox : 58.0.1
Code in the script as below:

```
public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"C:\\Users\\Veenu Gilotra\\Documents\\Selenium\\log.txt");
        //set profile for selenium 
        ProfilesIni allprof = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile prof = allprof.getProfile("TestUser");
        prof.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        prof.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false); 

        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setProfile(prof);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.geckoderiver", "C:\\tmp\\Browser_driver\\geckodriver.exe");

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```

logs:

```
Feb 20, 2018 9:09:02 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake   createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Missing 'type' parameter
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-MHUBI18', ip: '10.0.0.17', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 58.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 19384, moz:profile: C:\Users\Veenu Gilotra\AppD..., moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 55f77cc6-f94a-4ac3-9b6e-e6452d9883c4
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.new Instance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.new Instance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials, relevant _HTML_ and complete error stack trace please.

Comment: Are you sure it's the implicit wait line that's getting the exception?  It looks to me more like the instantiation of the driver itself that fails.  The problem almost certainly lies in the profile definition.

Comment: yes you are right, just found out there is a typo here ("webdriver.geckoderiver")  instead of ("webdriver.gecko.deriver)" .